# Chef : chef-client walks code first before executing it

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

In a Chef recipe I want to

1. unzip a file
2. use one of the files in the zip to iterate over the contents.

The problem I am having is when I run chef-client it fails saying 'No such file or directory' before it has even unzipped the file in step 1

Here is the code of the Provider:

```
    action :create do
      if @current_resource.exists
        converge_by("Create #{ @current_resource }") do
           unzip('realFileToUnzip','someLocation')  
           do_something_with_file('realFileToOpen')
        end
      end
    end
....
```

In the same provider file I have a def defined as follows

```
def unzip(fileToUnzip, unzipToLocation)
  bash "unzip" do
    user "root"
    cwd "/tmp"
    code <<-EOH
        unzip  -o #{fileToUnzip} -d #{unzipToLocation}
    EOH
  end
end
```

and this def also

```
def do_something_with_file(fileToConvert)
  ::File.open(fileToConvert, 'r') do |properties_file|
    properties_file.read.each_line do |line|
      puts line
    end
  end
end
```

It seems that chef-client is walking the code first before executing it.  So in the walk through the file is not present as it will not be there until it executes the unzip code.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: You need to wrap that code in `do_something_with_file` in a `ruby_block` resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Chef Docs](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_ruby_block.html):

> Use the ruby_block resource to execute Ruby code during a chef-client
>   run. Ruby code in the ruby_block resource is evaluated with other
>   resources **during convergence**, whereas Ruby code outside of a
>   ruby_block resource is evaluated **before** other resources, as the recipe
>   is compiled.

Then you have to create a ruby_block and insert the code of `do_something_with_file` into this resource. Maybe you have to make some modifications.

Good luck!